# US tourist visa for green card holder

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

My mom is applying for a tourist visa. She has been a permanent resident but went to live in her country of origin for a couple of years. The application asks for National Identification Number and US Social Security number. We provided the US social security number but I wonder if the national application number should be her A-number from the green card.

Also wondering what type of visa to choose:

1. Business/tourism (temporary visitor) B1/B2
2. Tourism/Medical treatment B2

She is coming here for tourism only.

Comment: Has she formally renounced her LPR status? That could incur issues with the visa process

Answer (score 6):

Specifically to your question, the National Identification Number refers to the ID number in her country of origin.

---

Unless your mother has formally renounced her LPR status, she'll need to do it first before applying for a visa (or apply for a returning resident SB-1 visa). There's no fee.

Here are the instructions on how to do it as listed on the [US embassy in the Netherlands webpage](https://nl.usembassy.gov/visas/immigrant-visas/abandoning-green-card/):

> - Download and fill in [form I-407 from the USCIS website](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407).
>
>   - Make sure you fill in your A number
>   - Sign the form
> - Send the following documents to the USCIS Eastern Forms Center (address below):
>
>   - The I-407 form
>   - The Green Card (also known as form I-551, if available).  If not available, the appropriate box in Part 1, item 11.b should be checked
>   - All other issued USCIS booklets and cards, if applicable
>   - Make sure to provide a return address.
>
> ```
>    USCIS Eastern Forms Center
>    Attn: I-407 Unit
>    124 Leroy Road
>    Williston, VT 05495
>    United States
> ```

Comment: If LPR is not renounced, is a visa even required?

Comment: @Simson yes, LPR who was absent from the US for more than a year without REP needs a visa to return (SB-1)